# Como hacer para fijar un boton al final de una tabla?

Tags: html, css, web

Tengo este ejemplo en [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/z9uszzOC32qgq1oPxGxG?p=preview%20p=preview)

Es una tabla con datos que al final tiene un boton **Mostrar mas...** con el que le doy mas datos a la tabla. El problema es que esta tabla es `scrolleable`, lo que intento hacer de alguna manera es que ese boton quede **fijo** o sea que cuando se scrollee horizontalmente se mantenga siempre visible el texto *Mostrar Mas...* en el centro del boton. Ya que si tiene muchos datos y se scrollea se pierde. No se si me explico, ese boton *Mostrar mas* siempre tiene que ser visible al usuario a pesar que scrollee mucho.

En este caso muevo el boton con la funcion scroll cada vez que scrollean sobre la tabla, el problema que surge cuando implemento esa solucion es este: Para probar el bug tenes que apretar 1 vez el boton *+ Datos*, llevar la barra de scroll hasta el final y luega apretar *- Datos*. Vas a ver un efecto medio raro con la barra de scroll y la tabla cuando quitas toda esa cantidad de columnas, ese efecto se da por la funcion del scroll que se esta usando para mover el boton.

Answer (score 1):

Saca el botón fuera del `div`

Te dejo el ejemplo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kI9jwW1AsOdMNXV2rulr?p=preview)